# Array of strings to IDropdownOption and back in TypeScript

Tags: arrays, typescript, maps

I have the following TypeScript code:

```
function getstringArray1DropdownOption(stringArray1Text: string): IDropdownOption {
    return {
        text: stringArray1Text,
        value: getstringArray1Value(stringArray1Text)
    };
}

function getstringArray2DropdownOption(stringArray2Text: string): IDropdownOption {
    return {
        text: stringArray2Text,
        value: stringArray2Text
    };
}

export const StringArray1[] = [
    "string1",
    "string2",
    ]
    .map(getStringArray1DropdownOption);

export const StringArray2: IDropdownOption[] = [
     "string3"
    ]
    .map(getStringArray2DropdownOption);
```

Now, I am trying to refactor such that I convert stringArray1 and stringArray2 **from** something of format (pseudocode):

```
var options = ["str1", "str2", ..].map((str) => makeDropDownOption(str));
```

**into** something of format (pseudocode):

```
var options = ["str1", "str2", ..];
var dropdownOptions = options.map((str) => makeDropDownOption(str));
```

What is the best way to do this? I keep running into type errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all that's needed once stringArray1 and stringArray2 are revised to just be string arrays:

```
var dropdownStringArray1FormatOptions =
    stringArray1.map(getStringArray1DropdownOption);

var dropdownStringArray2FormatOptions =
    stringArray2.map(getStringArray2FormatDropdownOption);
```